# fold-right in scheme

Tags: module, scheme, racket

I'm using DrRacket as scheme compiler. When I'm trying to use the fold-right function, I got "fold-right: unbound identifier in module in: fold-right." Do I need to include some library before calling this function?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want foldr which would fold-right.

Comment: @mwolfetech: Please post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for `foldr`.  [foldr](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) is the racket implementation of fold-right.

From the documentation:

> Like `map`, `foldl` applies a procedure to the elements of one or more
>   lists. Whereas `map` combines the return values into a list, `foldl`
>   combines the return values in an arbitrary way that is determined by
>   proc.

[…]

> [`foldr` is ] like `foldl`, but the lists are traversed from right to
>   left. Unlike `foldl`, `foldr` processes the lsts in space proportional
>   to the length of lsts (plus the space for each call to proc).

**Edit:**

You may also want to use the srfi/1 library as suggested by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young), particularily if you are expecting fold-right to work like the [srfi/1 recommendation](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap).  There are some subtle differences:

```
#lang racket
(require srfi/1)
(foldr list* '() '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
(fold-right list* '() '(a b c) '(1 2 3 4))
(foldr list* '() '(a b c) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Output:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 128 MB.
'{a 1 b 2 c 3}
'{a 1 b 2 c 3}
[ERROR] foldr: given list does not have the same size as the first list: '{1 2 3 4}
```

Note: `fold-right` does not error on different size lists, but you still only get the 1, 2, 3 atoms from the second list.  This matches the srfi/1 spec:

> The fold operation terminates when the shortest list runs out of
>   values

`foldr` does error.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `(require (only-in srfi/1 fold-right))` to the top of your code.

Comment: `foldr`, the Racket thing, is going to be more convenient to use.

Comment: For golfing, sure, but how else is `foldr` different to `fold-right` (notwithstanding having to import `srfi/1`)?

Comment: The latter point: it's just there, and you don't need to drag the rest of the srfi-1 mess in.

Comment: @chris-jester-young Investigated the difference, found at least one.  See my edit above.

Comment: @EliBarzilay There, that (edit) addresses your second point. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's a difference between several Racket functions and srfi-1 similar functions (eg, `map`), where the latter tends to be forgiving for lists of different sizes.  I find the `for*` forms much more convenient for cases where the sizes differ, and for the function forms I don't remember cases where I wanted such behavior (and I do remember a few bugs that it helped me catch).